# Vue Froala dynamic config options

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, froala

I'm using Vue Froala to do the image upload using the Froala config options which are basically an object added to the Vue data property. Something like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        config: {
            imageUploadURL: '/api/image/store',
            imageUploadParam: 'image',
            imageUploadParams: {id: this.id} //this is the dynamic ID
        }
    }
}
```

When I upload an image and those config options are triggered, the ID that I'm trying to pass is always `undefined`. I guess it is because when I first load the page, the Vue data properties are initialized at the very beginning and the dynamic ID that I'm retrieving from a prop, is not yet available.

I tried assigning the data property `imageUploadParams` a computed property that would return the ID but was still `undefined`

If I use a watcher to assign the ID afterwards, I get null. Here is what I get in the POST code (php)

```
+request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#45
  #parameters: array:1 [
    "id" => null
  ]
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a watch:

```js
data() {
  return {
    config: {
      imageUploadURL: '/api/image/store',
      imageUploadParam: 'image',
      imageUploadParams: { id: '' }
    }
  }
},
watch: {
  id(value) {
    this.config.imageUploadParams.id = value;
  }
}
```

Now whenever `id` changes, `config.imageUploadParams` will be set.

Assigning a variable in JavaScript sets the value at the time of the assignment. Since your id is empty when it's assigned, there's no reference to use later to access future async properties.  Assigning a computed won't help for the same reason.

Using `watch` for async, and `computed` for sync is a good general rule

*Edit from chat*

It seems `<froala>` isn't able to respond to your reactive data and is only using the initial config value.  Put a `v-if="id"` on the component to prevent it from being created until the id is ready:

```html
<froala v-if="id">
```

Comment: your solution makes a lot of sense but for some reasons, if I use a watcher I get null.
I even tried passing a static value inside the watcher, just to test it, and I still get null in the POST. But if I console.log imageUploadParams right after I assigned it, from within the watcher, it works. Could it be a scope issue?

Comment: I should have been more specific.  Can you show the javascript code where you send a post request using the `config` properties

Comment: so basically, Froala is an HTML editor and when I upload an image form my file system, Froala triggers those params and use imageUploadURL for  API call. I don't need anything else. The imageUploadParams is passing the object during the API call right after and image is being uploaded through the editor. But for some reasons, it's padding null. Of course, if I pass a static ID right there on the data properties, then it works.

Comment: I see.  Can you show how you use Froala?  Sounds like it's unaware of your reactive data.  I'll take a look at the docs.  You can also test that the watch is working by putting `{{ config }}` anywhere in the template

Comment: I made this sandbox. Not sure how to console.log the api call though.
https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-tree-rmrje?file=/src/components/editorfroala.vue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225566/discussion-between-dan-and-rolfo85).